# CSS: How to constantly display the bottom of the screen in a overflow window

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have an element that gets new data added to the bottom and I'm using 'overflow: scroll' to allow the scrolling down to see the new data.  However, I'd like to show those new updates automatically without the user having to scroll down herself. How can I do it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you want to happen if the amount if new data is longer than the container will show on screen at once?

Comment: Since the new data is coming at the bottom, I want the container to show the bottom all the time

Comment: Please can you show us how you are adding in new data and any relevant CSS/HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: sticky`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #a1ceff
}

main {
  background-color: #b1ffd5;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  height: 800px;
}

.new-data {
  background-color: #fffdb9;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #e0beff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  <div class="content">
    Other content
  </div>
  <div class="new-data">
    New data
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to work for my case. Thx all the same!

Comment: @Chea: Sorry to hear that. I can try to make it work if you add more info in your question, for example: your HTML (a mockup version with dummy data) and CSS, any CSS framework you're using, an image of your expected result (even Paint is fine), etc...